# simplexml_load_string from external XML returns white page

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to load some XML from an external API and turn it into a simplexml string. I'm using a cURL cross-domain proxy script to get the XML but when I run the XML through the simplexml_load_string function, all I get is a white screen.

If there's a way to turn it into JSON that's easier, i'd be more than happy to go down that route as XML is not my forte.

Here's the following code + XML i'm using:

External XML File:

```
<Sensors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Sensor>
        <ID>12</ID>
        <Name>EFM W.level</Name>
        <Series>Level</Series>
        <Unit>m</Unit>
    </Sensor>
    <Sensor>
        <ID>13</ID>
        <Name>EFM Wave h.</Name>
        <Series>Height</Series>
        <Unit>m</Unit>
    </Sensor>
</Sensors>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $url = 'LINK TO EXTERNAL XML';
    $headers = ($_POST['headers']) ? $_POST['headers'] : $_GET['headers'];
    $mimeType = ($_POST['mimeType']) ? $_POST['mimeType'] : $_GET['mimeType'];

    $session = curl_init($url);

    if ($_POST['url']) {
        $postvars = '';
        while ($element = current($_POST)) {
            $postvars .= key($_POST).'='.$element.'&';
            next($_POST);
        }
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
    }

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, ($headers == "true") ? true : false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($session);

    if ($mimeType != "") {
        header("Content-Type: ".$mimeType);
    }

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

    print_r($xml);

    curl_close($session);

?>
```

for reference, the cross-domain proxy script i'm using is - https://github.com/abdul/php-proxy/blob/master/proxy.php

Thanks.

Comment: Sure what you have right content in `$response` variable?

Comment: when i echo $response I get this -> https://s13.postimg.org/avuosdix3/Screen_Shot_2016_09_05_at_13_33_09.png

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the XML was UTF-16 encoded. Apparently simplexml doesn't like this so I used the following regex to change it to UTF-8.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(preg_replace('/(<\?xml[^?]+?)utf-16/i', '$1utf-8', $response));
```

Comment: You mean the XML declared a broken/wrong encoding and you fixed that. Replacing the encoding value in the XML declaration will not change the encoding of the document. If you fix works, then you got UTF-8 declared as UTF-16.

Comment: Yes, however I'm unable to change the encoding of the output XML. Hence why i've had to do it the way I have. As far as I can see so far nothing is broke and all is working. Will this produce any problems down the line?

Comment: It just means that the external API returns UTF-8 but declares that it is UTF-16. It is broken. DOM can load different encodings, but the declaration has to match the encoding.